# WordPress PHP multiple CRON

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm using last version of WordPress and I need to create CRON tasks. I have gone through the below link :
https://isabelcastillo.com/run-a-wp_schedule_event-recurrence-every-3-minutes#comment-46959

And this post :
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205421/multiple-wp-schedule-event-cron-jobs-in-plugin-cause-multi-execution

Here is my code:

```
function crons_activation( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['activation_time'] = array(
            'interval'  => 43200,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 12 hours', 'textdomain' )
    );
    $schedules['desactivation_time'] = array(
            'interval'  => 43140,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 12 hours', 'textdomain' )
    );     
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'crons_activation' );
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'activation_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'activation_time', 'activation_hook' );
}
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'desactivation_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'desactivation_time', 'desactivation_hook' );
}

function cron_activation() {
    $to = 'mymail@domain.com';
    $subject = 'SQL OK';
    $message = 'Query created';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $date = $date." 09:00:00";

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query('INSERT INTO TABLE ...');
}
function cron_desactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'activation_hook' );
    $to = 'mymail@domain.com';
    $subject = 'SQL KO';
    $message = 'Query deleted';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $date = $date." 09:00:00";

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query('DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `ID` = 1');
}
add_action('activation_hook', 'cron_activation');
add_action('desactivation_hook', 'cron_activation');
```

What I want:

I would like to create new SQL query to add a custom_post with status "future".
My SQL Query work perfectly.

<del>First problem : my CRON is executed randomly. I would like to execute this daily before 9:00 AM.</del>

**Second problem : before this execution, I have to delete this query because the post_id have to be unique but the second CRON never execute ...**

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Pls do not ask multiple questions in a single question. They make answering and searching a lot more difficult! Choose one question and go for it.

Comment: Edited for only one problem

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) plugin. Add your cron with any name and write your query in that function.
Hope that might help you.
Thanks

Comment: This plugin seems to be good. I can see my crons Events (created in my functions.php) in the table (back-office). But when i run my crons, the results is the same. And when i click on "Add PHP Cron Event" -> You cannot add or edit PHP cron events because your user account does not have the ability to edit files.